# AppGallery Connect App Signature failed to upload public key with "DSS Handle Fail" error

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, app-bundle, appgallery

I am trying to enable Huawei AppGallery Connect App Signature functionality to support uploading my App Bundle. When I try to upload the signing key, AppGallery Connect gives me an error message saying that it failed to upload the public key.

I looked at the network response and the error message was `“DSS Handle Fail”`.

I’m using the pepk tool version from here: https://www.gstatic.com/play-apps-publisher-rapid/signing-tool/prod/pepk.jar

I followed the same command as outlined in the following article and on the Huawei AppGallery App Signature page here:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-releasedapp

Does anyone use the same tool, command and have the same error? Please share if you have a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the App Signing service, please check as follows:

- If you upload your own key signature, the supported encryption algorithms and key length are as follows:
  RSA: 1024, 2048, 4096
  EC: NIST P-256

For more details, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-restriction?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: If the signature certificate encryption algorithms and key length are correct, please provide more info: your appid and what time you upload. :)